# Can't open the project on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, gemfile

Trying to start rails server from command - 'rails s', and traceback gives me this thing:

```
    33: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    32: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    31: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    30: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    29: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    28: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    27: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    26: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    25: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    24: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    23: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    22: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    21: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    20: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    19: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    18: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    17: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    16: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    15: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    14: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    13: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    11: from /home/cryptoproject/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    10: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
     9: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     8: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     7: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     6: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     5: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     4: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     3: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     1: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': libGeoIP.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/geoip_city-0.2.0/geoip_city.so (LoadError)
```

This project was build on another and older version of gems, and i've updated them from Gemfile, so i cleared the Gemfile.lock and installed the bundle again. What i need to do to fix this?

Comment: I don't have an answer at the moment, but some questions:
Have you tried `rbenv -rehash`?
What does `rails -v` and `ruby -v` show?
Does `/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/geoip_city-0.2.0/geoip_city.so` exist (and does it match with your ruby version)? If not, what provides the `geoip_city.so` file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with `geoip_city-0.2.0` gem.

This gem has a dependency that isn't installed (`GeoIP library`).

Follow [this tutorial](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/179-Geolocation-with-MaxMind-s-GeoIP-and-the-geoip-city-RubyGem) to install the gem and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help me. The same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your project was built on an 'older version of gems', it almost certainly means it was written on an older version of ruby, and you're using 2.5.0, released a few months ago.

Look for a .rbenv file or a .ruby-version file in your project. It will state which version of ruby to use. Alternatively ask someone who has it working what version of ruby they're using. Switch to that version, bundle install, and you should be good to go.